# How to find a column in a ndarray

Tags: python-3.x

Say i have a array

```
x = array([[ 0,  1,  2, 5],
        [ 3,  4,  5, 5],
        [ 6,  7,  8, 5],
        [ 9, 10, 11, 5]])
```

I need to find the position/index of `[3, 4, 5, 5]`. In this case, it should return `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array `y` that has all rows equal to the one you are looking for. Then, do an elementwise comparison `x == y` and find the rows where you get all `True`.

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5],
               [6, 7, 8, 5], [9, 10, 11, 5]])
y1 = np.array([[3, 4, 5, 5]] * 4)
print(np.where(np.all(x1 == y1, axis=1))[0]) # => [1]
```

This approach returns an array of the indices where the desired row appears.

```
y2 = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1]] * 4)
print(np.where(np.all(x1 == y2, axis=1))[0]) # => []

x2 = np.array([[3, 4, 5, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5],
              [6, 7, 8, 5], [9, 10, 11, 5]])
print(np.where(np.all(x2 == y1, axis=1))[0]) # => [0 1]
```